# Prepend/Append to Field Format in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

Consider the `eprint:arxiv`.  It is originally defined in `biblatex.def` as:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{%
  arXiv\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://arxiv.org/\abx@arxivpath/#1}{%
       \nolinkurl{#1}%
       \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
         {}
         {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}
     \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
       {}
       {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
```

but suppose I want all arXiv links to appear in red, then I need:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{eprint:arxiv}{{% Note the extra brace
  \color{red}%
  arXiv\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://arxiv.org/\abx@arxivpath/#1}{%
       \nolinkurl{#1}%
       \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
         {}
         {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}
     \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
       {}
       {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}}
```

The problem, however, is that this will override any modification to the `eprint:arxiv` field format that may have been introduced by another style.

Is there a way to make modifications to a field format in a style-agnostic manner?  Obviously, this will (and should) not modify the existing output of a style but just wrap around it (and as a result, I understand that if the style already has a `{\color{blue}...}` for their arXiv links, then wrapping it with `{\color{red}...}` won't do anything)

I thought that the `\savefieldformat` and `\restorefieldformat` commands may have been helpful, but it doesn't seem like it now and I can't find anything else within the documentation that might help.

As a little extra, it would be great if there was a function such as `\AddToFieldFormat[<entrytype...>]{<field>}{<code>}` so that modifying `eprint:arxiv` would be

```
\AddToField{eprint:arxiv}{{\color{red}#1}}
```

and where `#1` is the by the previous bibliography style's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package seems the way to go. Amongst others it provides `\xpretofieldformat` to prepend code to the field definitions

You just need

```
\xpretofieldformat{eprint:arxiv}{\color{red}}{}{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretofieldformat{eprint:arxiv}{\color{red}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{baez/article,itzhaki,wassenberg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  I'm glad there was an easy solution out there already :)